# Can't figure out the endpoints of NHL's official API.

Tags: api

The NHL has an official API that lacks any official documentation. There's one [github repo](https://github.com/dword4/nhlapi) trying to document it though.

I'm trying to access the statitistics for a team's goals per period. According to the documentation it can be found at: `?stats=goalsByGameSituation&season=20162017`.

So I go to this [endpoint](https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/15/?stats=goalsByGameSituation&season=20162017) but I'm getting what I looked for.

Anyone experienced with the NHL API please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `?expand=team.stats` or add `/stats` to the path to get stats for a team:

- https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/15?expand=team.stats&season=20152016
- https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/15/stats?season=20152016

However, they don't include the goals per period and those endpoints ignore the `?stats=...` query parameter.  The `?stats=goalsByGameSituation&season=20162017` query string is for people, for example

- https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8471214/stats?stats=goalsByGameSituation&season=20162017

To get the goals per period for teams you could calculate the stat you want by aggregating [game line scores](https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020001/linescore), for example:

- https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020001/linescore

You could also aggregate the player stats over their roster (`teams/{id}/roster`) to get an **approximate** team statistic. It doesn't allow you to add a team query parameter for players so you can't separate player stats by team when players are traded.

Also note that the Github repo is no longer being maintained. You can use the [GitLab one](https://gitlab.com/dword4/nhlapi) for the most up-to-date version.